# Duplicate tab in tabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout

When I am clicking on the tab a duplicate custom icon is created on the bottom of the current tab. How to get rid of this?

I am setting the custom title using below code:

```
private void setIcon(String title, int icon, boolean isSelected, int position) {

        LinearLayout tab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        final CircleImageView tabImage = (CircleImageView) tab.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);

        if (isSelected){
            //add shadow to image.
            tabImage.setBorderColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.white));
            tabImage.setBorderWidth(10);
        }

        Glide.with(getContext()).load(icon).into(tabImage);

        tabTitle.setText(title);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setCustomView(tab);
    }
```

**What I am trying to do:**
When the user clicks on tab add the border of the outside of the image. So to do this I am adding addTabSelectedListener on the tablayout as below:

```
 tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                //add shadow on selected tab
                setIcon(getTitle(tab.getPosition()), getIcon(tab.getPosition()),true,tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                //remove shadow from previous tab
                setIcon(getTitle(tab.getPosition()), getIcon(tab.getPosition()),false,tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            }
        });
```

But new tab icon is added just under the old icon instead of replacing the old icon.

**What I have tried:**

1. use of tabLayout.removeTab(tab)
2. use of tabLayout.removeTabAt(tab.getpostion());
3. use of tabLayout.removeAllTabs();

All them result into NullPointerException.

Edit :

**As Arpan Suggested:**

View view = tab.getCustomView();
but how will I get the tabTitle and tabImage from this view?

**Edit 2:**

Ok I am able to do some part correct i.e. Image is loading correctly but title is moving at top instead of below.

Code:

```
LinearLayout customTab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
                final CircleImageView tabImage = (CircleImageView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
                final TextView tabTitle = (TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tab_title);

                tabTitle.setText(getTitle(tab.getPosition()));



                Glide.with(getContext()).load(getIcon(tab.getPosition())).into(tabImage);

                tab.setCustomView(tabImage);
```

If I do this, Image set perfectly but title goes to the top of it. I know it is because I am not setting tabTitle in the tab. How will I do that?

If I use the linear layout and set it than it create duplicate tab.

**Edit 3:**

All done, I just call the setcustomViewAgain for tabtitle;

Comment: did you solve your problem? i am also facing the same problem, can you help please

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK everytime in your `setIcon()` method you are creating a new instance of tab view.That seems to be the problem . What you should do is that you should pass view from the tab listener and pass that to set Icon .

Yous should pass tab.`getCustomView()` as view to you `setIcon()` function and get `tabTitle` and `tabImage` from that view.

**EDIT**
For getting your textview you will have to do

```
tvTitle = (TextView)tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
```

Comment: setIcon() method you are creating a new instance of tab view. Is         tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setCustomView(tab); creating the new Instance??? How will I get the tabTitle and tabImage from that View?

Comment: that is view which tab is holding.Have you tried it?

Comment: Yup, I tried. I think setCustomView need a view but I have two views tabTitle and tabIcon. I think it need a layout that is R.layout.custom_tab but there is no way to get the reference of this. Since using findViewById i can get only tabTitle and tabIcon but both are in a layout custom_tab. So my question now is how will I get the layout using the tab.

Comment: I have changed the code accordingly but still getting the same response. You can check the edit also.